# Как определить позицию курсора в div с contenteditable="true"

Tags: javascript

Есть длинный текст в div с contenteditable="true" и курсор, который находится на какой-то позиции в тексте. Как мне определить позицию курсора с учётом innerHTML и с учётом что в содержимом есть html теги?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Оно - https://qna.habr.com/q/123789?ysclid=ll3ddxmro2665390981 ?

Comment: Да видел этот пример, спасибо. Но у меня проблема что в тексте который вводится так же есть ссылки на пользователей, то есть в самом поле это отображается как обычный текст и ваш пример работает именно с этим обычным текстом, а мне надо вставлять смайлики с учётом html, где ссылка на пользователя отображается к теге <a> и соответственно это совершенно другая позиция курсора

Comment: Так может вы пример приведёте? Что у вас, как решали? Из вопроса сейчас ничего ж не понятно ))

Comment: Да согласен, извиняюсь) я скрин к вопросу прикрепил. словами это сложно объяснить)

Comment: А искать позицию в `innerText` вместо `innerHTML` вы пробовали?

Comment: Да ищет как раз той функцией пример которой вы дали

Comment: А подставляет какой? Саму функцию дайте уже )

Comment: вот вы же в примере дали
function getCursorPosition(parent) {
  let selection = document.getSelection()
  let range = new Range
  range.setStart(parent, 0)
  range.setEnd(selection.anchorNode, selection.anchorOffset)
  return range.toString().length
}

Comment: В примере мы получаем позицию в диве. Где ваша функция, которая затем пытается вставить смайлик в див по позиции курсора?

Comment: пока работаю надо получением. думаю вставку сделать следующим образом. разделяю строку до курсора и после курсора вставляю туда смайл опять жешь с помощью тега img и загоняю это всё в innerHTML